# SQL cohort calculations

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have my table of players activity like this:

| user_id | event_name | install_date | event_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | active | 2021-03-01 | 2021-03-01 |
| 1 | active | 2021-03-01 | 2021-03-01 |
| 1 | active | 2021-03-01 | 2021-03-02 |
| 2 | active | 2021-03-02 | 2021-03-02 |
| 2 | active | 2021-03-02 | 2021-03-04 |
| 2 | active | 2021-03-02 | 2021-03-04 |

and I want to calculate cohort retention like this

| user_id | install_date | ret0 | ret1 | ret2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-03-01 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2021-03-02 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Help me please to write sql query. Thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want to compare the `event_date` to the `install_date` and keep track of when "x" days appear between the two:

```
select user_id,
       max(case when event_date = install_date then 1 else 0 end) as ret1,
       max(case when event_date = date_add(install_date, interval 1 day) then 1 else 0 end) as ret1,
       max(case when event_date = date_add(install_date, interval 2 day) then 1 else 0 end) as ret2
from t
group by user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach - less verbose and better manageable and expandable to more generic cases

```
select * from (
  select user_id, install_date, date_diff(event_date, install_date, day) diff
  from `project.dataset.table`
)
pivot (count(diff) as ret for diff in (0, 1, 2))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Btw, if you want to output 1 or 0 in respective columns - you can adjust above to

```
select * from (
  select user_id, install_date, date_diff(event_date, install_date, day) diff
  from `project.dataset.table` 
  group by 1,2,3
)
pivot (count(diff) as ret for diff in (0, 1, 2))
```

in this case  - output is

[image]